# Combining rows if text is same before certain character

Tags: r, text

I have a data frame similar to this. I want to sum up values for rows if the text in column "Name" is the same before the **-** sign.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove everything after `"-"` using `sub` and then use [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

```
df$Name <- sub("-.*", "",df$Name)
aggregate(cbind(val1, val2)~Name, df, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do. But can you help me if the data frame has the same characters in other column(s) how can I use only unique?

Comment: @GoranKošutić Maybe you should post a new question with these details.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a data.table solution.

Data:

```
df = data.table(
  Name = c('IRON - A', 'IRON - B', 'SABBATH - A', 'SABBATH - B'),
  val1 = c(1,2,3,4),
  val2 = c(5,6,7,8)
)
```

Code:

```
df[, Name := sub("-.*", "", Name)]

mat = df[, .(sum(val1), sum(val2)), by = Name]

> mat
       Name V1 V2
1:    IRON   3 11
2: SABBATH   7 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `rbind` your 2 tables (top and bottom) into one data frame and then use `dplyr` or `data.table`. The `data.table` would be much faster for large tables.

```
data_framme$Name <- sub("-.*", "", data_frame$Name)

library(dplyr)
data_frame %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)


library(data.table)
data.frame <- data.table(data.frame)
data.frame[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=Name ]
```

Comment: This solution would separate IRON MAIDEN - A and IRON MAIDEN - B. OP wants to identify Name groups with the same name before the "-" sign.

Comment: Thanks @J.G. for pointing this out, I have edited my answer.